# Storyboard inside datatemplate Windows 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-8, windows-8.1

Is it possible to Begin a storyboard from code behind(.cs file) which is inside a datatemplate. The Below code is not working please advice me.

```
<HubSection Width="800"  x:Name="Section2" Header="Section 2" Foreground="Black">
       <DataTemplate x:Name="DataTemplateNotificaiton" >
             <Grid Background="White" Width="700" Height="500" Margin="-20" >   
                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Margin="0,302,0,-302" Canvas.ZIndex="0"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                                    <Canvas.Resources>
                                        <Storyboard x:Name="TileAnimation">
                                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-1.5"/>
                                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="-252"/>
                                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </Canvas.Resources>
                                    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform/>
                                    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="panel1" Margin="30,30,0,0" Text="sdasdasdasd" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="32" >
                                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="panel2"  Margin="30,7,0,0"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="adasdasdasdasd" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" FontSize="22"  Canvas.Top="98">
                                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform/>
                                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                    </TextBlock>


                                </Canvas>


                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HubSection>
```

c# code behind:

```
Storyboard anim = (Storyboard)FindName("TileAnimation");
        anim.Begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but complicated and not recommended, when you want to keep your code readable.
What I recommend is, develop a userControl which contains everything what is currently in your Template, and then design your animations in that control. 
You can easily add this new control in the datatemplate instead of the code above. That makes it also easier to test the control.

HTH-Oliver

Comment: yes Oliver, If I do in that way, the storyboard is returning null in the usercontrol.

Comment: Where do you call this Code? Right in the Constructor? Or later in the Loaded-Event?